# WD My Book World Edition and Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, mybook

This is my setup in the office:

- a DSL modem
- router attached to modem
- 2 PC's running Windows 7 (home edition, 64bit) connected to router via network cable
- laptop running Windows XP SP2 "connected" to router via wireless
- WD My Book World Edition connected to router via network cable

The problem is that I can't access folders on My Book that are protected from Windows 7 (in XP it works).
I can see the My Book in "Network" in Win7 and I can access folders that have no protection. But if I create a "folder share" that only one user has access to it does not work.
I see the folder but when I click it and enter the username/password (that I've set in the admin panel of My Book) Win7 gives me this message:

> \\192.168.1.103\jan_private is not
>   accessible. ou might not have
>   permission to use this network
>   resource. Contact the administrator of
>   this server to find out if you have
>   access permissions. Multiple
>   connections to a server or shared
>   resource by the same user, using more
>   than one user name, are not allowed.
>   Disconnect all previous connections to
>   the server or shared resource and try
>   again.

What is the problem here? I can't figure it out ...

update: still haven't solved this ... from what I understand this isn't strictly related to My Book but any NAS disk ...

**update2:** I've now managed to access the folder if I enter the IP of the disk into the address bar, but I still can't access it via it's name (which Windows use by default if you click on the disk in My Computer).

Comment: Whats a protected folder? I'm sorry i am not familiar with Windows file systems

Comment: I don't know the internals. I've created the folder with the admin panel (which you access trough the browser) and you can set who has access to what.
I didn't create the folder with Windows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution (with the help of my local tech web page). The problem was that I was trying to access folders that have different users assigned to, and since I was already loged-in with one user I couldn't log with another.

Problem solved :)